# Emacs - issues about hide-ifdef-mode

Tags: c, emacs, macros, elisp

How to autoload hide-ifdef-mode?
Following implementations does not work for me:

```
;; auto hide-ifdef-mode from starting
(dolist (func '(hide-ifdef-mode hide-ifdef-mode-menu hide-ifdef-block
                hide-ifdef-define hide-ifdef-undef
                hide-ifdef-use-define-alist hide-ifdef-set-define-alist
                hide-ifdef-toggle-read-only hide-ifdef-toggle-outside-read-only
                hide-ifdef-shadowing))
   (autoload func "hideif" "Hiding several ifdef blocks" t))
```

or just:

```
(autoload 'hide-ifdef-mode "hideif" "hideifdefmode" t)
```

A related issue - How to make that all actions with hide-ifdef-mode have been applied for all *.c and *.h files (buffers)?
Like, if I define some macro (C-c @ d) or list of macro and apply it (C-c @ h) this action would be performed for other files (and for new opened files too).

Comment: `hide-ifdef-mode` is already autoloaded for you without you having to do anything, so I don't really understand the main question.

Comment: In Emacs, `autoload` has a very specific meaning. Do you actually want to turn `hide-ifdef-mode` on in C buffers automatically?

Comment: Yes, in my case it is a very useful tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really looking for a way to enable `hide-ifdef-mode` automatically when you are in `c-mode`. In Emacs, this is done with [hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html).

Try adding this to your configuration:

```lisp
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'hide-ifdef-mode)
```

Note thate Emacs *does* have a feature called [autoload](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html), which does something different:

> The autoload facility lets you register the existence of a function or macro, but put off loading the file that defines it. The first call to the function automatically loads the proper library, in order to install the real definition and other associated code, then runs the real definition as if it had been loaded all along. Autoloading can also be triggered by looking up the documentation of the function or macro (see [Documentation Basics](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Documentation-Basics.html#Documentation-Basics)).

Comment: Thanks! It's working! Any ideas about the second issue? MB is necessary to use some mods for multiple buffers?

Comment: @folq, sorry, I don't know how to do that.